# Code generator to create ADO.NET SqlParemeter array from stored procedure inputs?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, code-generation

I have SQL Server stored procedures which have several inputs. I want to save time from manually creating C# ADO.NET sqlParameter arrays as in

```
sqlParameter[] sqlParameters = 
                { new SqlParameter("customerID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, string.Empty, DataRowVersion.Default, custID) .......
```

Any code generator which can this and a template which can do this? If you mention a code generator, please mention which template. Like which one for [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator).

Comment: Do you really need in that format? Or any format would do? If any format would do then you can use netTiers

Comment: Any reason it has to generate these? Could you use Entity Framework to call the stored procedures?

Comment: Yes in that format. I am stuck with this because its the standard at work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a large number of stored procedures, you can write a macro in Visual Studio to generate the code (see [this](http://waldev.blogspot.com/2010/08/visual-studio-macros.html) for example). Actually, depending on how you write the macro, it can handle a large number too.

If you have no requirement for a manually crafted DAL, then you probably should consider using an ORM (Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL .. etc) which will generate the code for you.

Comment: I need something which works out of the box or needs little rework. What macro which can go to a stored procedure and create such statements? It seems it's easiier to write c# code to do that. Another ORM is not an option. I specifically mentioned that in my comment.

Comment: Sorry for that. It's because of the way I work (I write all sprocs by hand and keep them in a text file which I use to generate the related DAL methods later). But of course this might not be convenient to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link (and I am using) to some code that I believe will do what you want - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DetermineSql2005SPParams.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataSet using Add New Item. Then, from Server Explorer, drag a stored procedure onto the design surface.

This will create a few things:

1. A `DataSet`, that you can ignore
2. A Table Adapter named "QueriesTableAdapter". It will contain
3. A protected array of commands, complete with full parameter lists
4. A method with the name of the stored procedure, and which takes appropriate parameters, and which calls the stored procedure through an element of the array of commands.

Now, since the command collection is protected, you have to do a little more work. On the design surface, press F7 (View Code). This will create a DataSet1.cs file. Delete the contents and add the following:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication.Data.DataSet1TableAdapters
{
    public partial class QueriesTableAdapter
    {
        public SqlCommand aspnet_Membership_CreateUser_Command
        {
            get { return (SqlCommand) CommandCollection[0]; }
        }
    }
}
```

(I had a web application open, and it was using the standard ASP.NET database, so that's the stored procedure in the example)

This will allow your code to access `QueriesTableAdapter.aspnet_Membership_CreateUser_Command.Parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [SqlSharpener project](https://github.com/aeslinger0/sqlsharpener). It can parse the sql files in your SSDT project at **design-time** and then you can call an included T4 template to create C# wrappers for all your stored procedures, or you can build your own T4 template if you want.